# Problem with InstallForge and CustomTkinter

Tags: python, installation, exe

I am currently working on a gui with the custom tkinter lib.

I created the .exe file by adding the CustomTkinter with auto-py-to-exe

Then I use the InstallForge software because I want to share my file.

After that I got my setup file, it works on my computer but not on my friends one.

Do you guys now why ?

I try to use other software like Inno Setup compiler but the problem is still the same, the application cant be launched.

I run is as admin : result : the application cant be launched.

[Here is the files that I add in the software Install Forge](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7nQF8.png)

Thank you.

Comment: Hello.  I add a photo but I don't think it is a code problem because it works fine I don't really understand why it works on my computer and not on my other one laptop

Comment: hello @Harith, were you able to figure it out ? I am also facing something similar

Comment: Hey, nope. 
Still trying to figure it out.
I use other installer and the problem is still the same.

Comment: hey, did you check advanced installer ? I tried 3-4 installers and none of them worked for some reason, but this one worked, check this out : https://www.advancedinstaller.com/

Comment: Hey thanks l'll try it out.

Comment: I how did you do it ?
I don't really understand how to use it

Comment: First did you make sure that your exe/msi worked on your pc ?

Comment: Hey, the exe ?
The one that I created with py to exe ?

Comment: yes, bdw if you can check this project, [Cnipe](https://github.com/QuicqDev/cnipe). I am building this screenshot app which takes beautiful screenshots. This might give you some inspiration for implementations